# Add Tag i2p-zero

Tags: discussion

[i2p-zero](https://github.com/i2p-zero/i2p-zero) doesn't live in the [monero project namespace](https://github.com/monero-project), but still the java package name is **org.getmonero**.i2p-zero

So, is the monero stackexchange the right place for Q&A about i2p-zero ? If yes, can you add the tag `i2p-zero` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is the monero stackexchange the right place for Q&A about i2p-zero?

I would say so, yes. It was developed specifically with Monero in mind (by a Monero contributor, knaccc).

That said, if a question is more specifically about i2p, there maybe a more appropriate SE site.

> can you add the tag i2p-zero?

Yes, done. Thanks for spotting it was missing.